# Granny gear not usable

Tags: derailleur-rear

I have Cyctrac EM5 with SHIMANO DEORE/M6100-12S derailleur. In others gears it's working fine. Here is a video of problem: https://www.youtube.com/shorts/V0Lr_IUTb7c

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

Issue solved. The problem seems it was Sram chain on Shimano gear. The second issue is that derailleur was not properly installed. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is not a new chain on an old cassette

Possibly Low limit screw is a touch too far out. Looks and sounds like the chain is trying to walk up the ramps to the mythical gear 13.

Shift to 11 to take pressure off screw & limit cam and increase the limit screw by 1/4 turn before shifting back down to 12 to see if the situation improves. Repeat as needed.

Comment: It's properly adjusted. I tried another time, but then I saw where the problem can be. The cassette is new - 300km (new bike). I changed the chain but the problem remain. When under pressure the chain wont sit properly. Mayby a better cassette will fix this issue? The cassette is Sunshine-12s 11-50T